# Fill a row with a value until column index saved in a variable of dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a little problem with a dataframe in R. My dataframe `Base` looks tike this (I add the `dput()` version in the final side):

```
   ID I1 I2 I3 Col
1 001  0  2  1   2
2 002  1  2 NA   3
3 003  3  2 NA   1
```

My dataframe has an id variable, numeric variables (`I1,I2,I3`) and an index variable named `Col`. I want to fill the all the rows with a value of `1` starting in the column `I1` until the column whose index is saved in `Col`. For example in the case of the second row `Col` shows a value of three, so the filling process with `1` should start from column `I1` until column `I3`. The same logic is applied to the other rows. I have tried with this solution but it doesn't work:

```
Base[-1] <- apply(Base[2:5],1,function(x) {x[1:x[4]]=1})
```

Because this code fills all the rows with `1` without considering the index column saved in `Col`. With this code I got this:

```
   ID I1 I2 I3 Col
1 001  1  1  1   1
2 002  1  1  1   1
3 003  1  1  1   1
```

I would like to get a data frame like this:

```
   ID I1 I2 I3 Col
1 001  1  1  1   2
2 002  1  1  1   3
3 003  1  2 NA   1
```

Also, I have tried changing `x[1:x[4]]=1` inside the function by `x[1:x[x[4]]]=1` but it doesn't work. The `dput()` version of `Base` is the next:

```
Base=structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "003"), I1 = c(0, 1, 3), 
    I2 = c(2, 2, 2), I3 = c(1, NA, NA), Col = c(2, 3, 1)), .Names = c("ID", 
"I1", "I2", "I3", "Col"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a matrix of the row,col indexes of the values you want to change to one. You can then use this matrix to subset and replace values in the data.frame. For example

```
idx <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(a,b) 
    cbind(a,match(paste0("I",1:b), colnames(Base))), 
    seq_along(Base$Col), Base$Col))

Base[idx]<-1
```

which gives

```
   ID I1 I2 I3 Col
1 001  1  1  1   2
2 002  1  1  1   3
3 003  1  2 NA   1
```

as desired.

But going back to your original attempt, the problem is vector recycling (and mis-transposition). When you do an assignment (`x<-1`) the values that's returned is the right hand side value (`1`). This value ends up getting recycled to fill the length of the column. You want to instead return the full-length (transformed) `x` from your function rather than just the values you replaced. The function you pass to apply does not make changes in place, it expects new values to be returned. So you could do

```
Base[-1] <- t(apply(Base[2:5],1,function(x) {x[1:x[4]]=1; x}))
```

or

```
Base[-1] <- t(apply(Base[2:5],1,function(x) {replace(x,1:x[4],1)}))
```

I've also had to add in a `t()` to transpose the returned matrix due to the way `apply()` returns values.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by `row/column` indexing

```
Base[-1][cbind(rep(1:nrow(Base), Base$Col), sequence(Base$Col))] <- 1
Base
#   ID I1 I2 I3 Col
#1 001  1  1  1   2
#2 002  1  1  1   3
#3 003  1  2 NA   1
```